# C# VS2008 Compiler picking up wrong Methods

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c#-2.0

I've got a really odd problem when building a project in VS2008. Having made some completely un-related changes I started getting a build error. Basically the compiler picks up the incorrect extension method.

---

**Assembly1:** References Assembly4.

```
[DebuggerHidden]
public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(false), CLSCompliant(false)]
public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IConcreteCollection collection)
{}
```

**Assembly3:** Only References Assembly1. Note that CustomClass does not implement IConcreteCollection.

```
List<CustomClass> list = new CustomClass[].ToList();
```

**Assembly4:** IConcreteCollection defined.

---

**Error message:**

> The type
>   'Assembly4.Namespace.IConcreteCollection' is
>   defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference
>   to assembly 'Assembly4.Namespace, Version=...'.

---

As you can see, Assembly3 has incorrectly attempted to use the wrong Extension in Assembly1, despite the fact that the types do not match.

VS2008 goto-definition however works correctly and points to the correct method in Assembly1.

Anyone else experienced this or know what might be the problem?

Comment: Where is IConcreteCollection defined? If you could give a *complete* example with the types in all three assemblies, that would help.

Comment: @Jon: apologies. IConcreteCollection would be defined in another assembly (so Assembly4), only referenced by Assembly2 in this example.

Comment: So does *anything* have a reference to Assembly2? This sounds very strange, but a full example would really help. If you do a completely clean build, does that fix it?

Comment: @Jon: I had a look to see if anything referenced assembly2 and discovered a mistake in my example. Different namespaces same assembly :S. Both the extension methods are actually in the same Assembly (sorry about that). Assembly3 however doesn't know anything about the IConcreteCollection. A full rebuild doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now you've updated the question, the error makes perfect sense. If you're going to have a public method in Assembly1 which references a type from Assembly4, anyone *potentially* using that method Assembly1 needs a reference to Assembly4. Basically the compiler looks at the candidate method and doesn't know enough to decide whether it's applicable or not.

Just add the reference to Assembly3 from Assembly4 and all should be well. If you don't *want* to add that reference, you should change the name of one of the methods, or make it internal/private. Don't ask the compiler to examine signatures it doesn't understand :)

Comment: Hmm, I understand the behaviour in that case. I think it slightly odd that we can determine we the type in VS and would kinda expect the compiler to be able to handle this case, but I can see why it might be a limitation. I've worked around it as in this case those Assembly's should be agnostic from each other. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: @Ian: Imagine if `IConcreteCollection` were a type which had a user-defined conversion from `CustomClass[]` - it's not impossible...